# Spherical vs Circular(planar) wormholes; possibility?

Tags: science-fiction, space-travel, spacetime-dimensions, wormholes

*I know that 'they' are theoretical and hypothetical, but please justify deep down to your understanding and I'll try to grab-up as much*

### Origin of Problem:

Thanks to the fantasy and fiction, there are **different types and shapes of wormholes**, that can (or may) exist. Shape of given wormhole as seen on either of its faces varies from being a circle to sphere, or some higher dynamic geometry.

[image: Artist Concept of a Wormhole Travel]

In some wormholes (in literature or cinema), transfer of "Living-Being or Material or Energy" takes place instantaneously; while for others that transfer takes considerable time. (i.e.: In some wormholes, things just appear on the other side as they go-through, while in other wormholes, they technically work like a super-slingshot, things are traveling at great velocities.)

### Conflict: Circular vs Spherical wormholes

> For Circular wormhole, assuming its existence. I can say that it will be a PLANE. Not the surface, but plane, from where the traveling and/or teleportation-things happen. Thus, in theory, it acts like a HOLE to a different space-time and there is nothing physical in that region- no physical matter from the wormhole to be felt, that's why its called as worm-hole. But for spherical wormhole to exist, matter can't be there inside, otherwise it will be a physical thing (like a black-hole or star, say) that lies there in space. And it can't be a whole sphere because that'll add-up to DIMENSION being different on the other side.

It just doesn't seem possible to me, because assuming that a spherical wormhole does exists, and something enters it (interacts with it, to be more accurate), to go on the other space-time. When and where is it going to interact with the wormhole? Is it some spherical plane or some imaginary volume? The working of spherical wormhole confuses me or is not clear to me. Help!

---

**So the conflict boils down to these questions:**

*(Please try to consider spherical wormhole different from any black hole; if possible)*

**1. Is it really possible for a wormhole to be Spherical? If possible then, justification of spherical wormhole's existence?**

**2. What exists in spherical wormhole, under the spherical plane?**
(I've only encountered resources describing- tunnels through space-time, none with the concept of sphere though.)

---

If I've missed or deviated from some relevant points please feel free to correct me, as this is my first question here. In advance, Thanking you! :)

Comment: Please, one question per question :)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. Please note we prefer to give sharp answer to specific problems. We try to avoid writing whole books answering multiple questions. It is perfectly fine to spread related questions on multiple, single question, posts. Else the question can be put on hold.

Comment: @L.Dutch So is it a good idea to split that question now? or waiting is good. Its obvious to assume the ignorance- the question/post may face being too long. Help!?

Comment: Sure it is. Use the edit function to modify your question to contain a single problem. When posting other related questions, link to the original one by using the share function. You can also give a name to the series of question, if you think this can better identify the group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is INSIDE a Wormhole?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/105041/what-is-inside-a-wormhole)

Comment: @L.Dutch I tried splitting my questions and was about to finalize it to a shared post, but then some relevant(but not complete) answer from 'Ghedipunk" appeared. So I kept things same, only changing the layout of question. But now I see it's on hold. Please tell me if it's good now. I learnt that besides thinking broad, I need to be very specific. As this helps both sided.

Comment: Ghedipunk is wrong though so please edit the question so it can be answered properly. His understanding of some of the physics could mislead you into believing something false.

Comment: This was edited and put in the VTR queue, but I'm going to recommend it not be opened yet.  Jit.S, do you understand (insofar as we understand wormholes at all) that a "hole" in 3D space can ony present itself as a sphere?  This is because the "hole" must "exit" in all directions simultaneously and you "transport" outside of regular 3D space.  Wormholes are often conceptualized as 2D planes because it's whomping hard for humans to think in 4Dish terms.  You should research the matter before asking here.  Start at [space.com](https://www.space.com/20881-wormholes.html) for a good start.

Comment: @Renan; "What is INSIDE a Wormhole?" tells me all about those 'tunnels' but I'm concerned with the spherical ones. So, I asked. I did a bit of research prior, but might be lacking.

Comment: @Jit.S the referenced question contains the answer. There are no spheric wormholes.

Comment: Let's ask a different way: A wormhole (if they exist) has an entrance, a passage, and an exit, not unlike a hallway with a door at each end.  Are you asking about the shape of the hallway (the wormhole passage), or the shape of the doors (the wormhole entrance and exit)?

Comment: Shape of the doors is that concerns me! Thank you for super simplyfying! :) @JBH

Answer (score 2):

Wormholes are purely theoretical.

But the common understanding is the curving and shortcut of spacetine approach.

Spacetime is folded and a much shorter way is made.

This means wormholes are not teleportation but instead a quicker way to get where you are going. THEY ARE NOT FTL you travel at the same velocity in a wormhole as outside you just travel a shorter distance.

They are spherical, just like black holes.

Think of spacetime as a cloth and punch a hole through the cloth. Then make it 3D. The 3D form of a hole is a spherical hole.

Also entanglement and wormholes are different so pick one.

Comment: @P. Lord Appreciate your response. But it is still lacking the details I'm looking for. I know my question(s) are a bit long here, but please try to have my point of conflict. I agree that wormholes are both theoretical and hypothetical, but still I've got some blurry points.

Comment: PS: They might be somewhat different. But, entanglement(in quantum cosmology) and wormholes are analogous and indeed two sided of the same coin. You can find some ongoing research on that part also.

Comment: I see no way how entanglement (two particles having the same state when measured) and wormholes (a shortcut through spacetime) are connected. But anyway it is not teleportation but it can be very quick.

Comment: You can get a clue from (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.04354.pdf) P34 | Large System Teleportation. Skip to this section for a brief. And this is one of those materials I studied while searching, but not the only one.

Comment: After reading 3-4 articles on that paper A) It is so theoretical that is a theory about a theory about a theory which are all unproven B) The wormholes that they suggest are completely different to your typical wormhole in SciFi, these are minute wormholes linking individual particles that are entangled.

Comment: If you want to enter a chat with me I can explain how this even if it were true is not what you think it is.