# Could these new wormholes be used as a hammer space?

Tags: science-based, wormholes

So, if you remember these two questions:

[What can these negative-mass-free wormholes be used for?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/166848/32097) 
and [Scientific explanation for summoned creatures](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/166758/32097) , you probably know what I'm talking about.

Basically, I wanted to have summonable creatures in my setting. There were two ways to accomplish that:

The Attack-on-Titan way suffered from the problem that synthesizing a 60-meter Hermann Göring from the ground up in stopped time has [severe consequences](https://youtu.be/ACdAG_nM2W4?t=45) once time begins moving again that, realistically, should affect the summoned creature as well, instantaneously roasting it.

The other is the hammerspace route. Basically, on the dark side of the moon, there's a place, called the titan realm. The place is Anakin Skywalker's nightmare, since it's basically a huge desert with a stable temperature of 20 °C. The titan realm is renown for its coffee, which tastes pretty good despite being 100% sand.

When not "prepared" for summoning, the card-creatures recuperate here.

Once the notice is sent, the wormhole locates the card-creature and "eats" them, where they stand and regardless what they're doing, this has to be done to make sure they get in place on time (this wormhole is always longer than going straight).

The card creature is supposed to wait just by the entrance for the signal to come out, making it seem like they teleported there.

Now, there's a problem, however, for a start, this requires both entrances of the wormhole to be able to move.

**I'm unsure if the wormholes could move without disconnecting, and if they can indeed be moved (not by heartfelt words, though) how should they be moved?**

Answer (score 2):

I've read [the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05687) written by the researchers in the article you reference. I've also read its follow-up: ["Creating a Traversable Wormhole"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02187).

Disclaimer: I'm not a physicist, and much of it goes over my head.

I don't think I can give you a simple yes or no answer, but the situation looks like this:

- The two mouths of a wormhole have a tendency to move away from each other. This in turn destabilises the wormhole. And that movement will accelerate. The authors go to a lot of trouble to keep this movement as close to zero as possible, so as to keep the wormhole stable.
- When they do move uncontrollably away from each other, I couldn't find any information about the direction of their movement. Perhaps it's the direction that's optimal for increasing the distance between them as far and as fast as possible. The papers didn't seem to consider the question of influencing that direction.
- The authors didn't seem able to get the mouths of the wormhole *absolutely* stationary, just very close. I don't know what sort of velocity would count as "very close" to zero on the kind of scales involved. Still, small movements to nearby areas on the same part of one of Earth's continents *might* be okay. Or at least, you might be able to get away with them with only an X% chance of breaking the wormhole.

  *(Other answerers, if you're able to deduce information on permissible differences from the papers, please post!)*
- Like I said, I couldn't find anything addressing the question of "Can the direction or velocity of movements of a wormhole mouth be influenced by the human user in any way?" in those papers.
- I wonder if there might be a slight loophole, whereby if you move the mouth at the other end of the wormhole so that its distance stays constant with the end you were moving in the first place, you might keep the wormhole stable.

On a cheerier note, future research into these wormholes may go some way toward addressing these questions and finding ways around the difficulties. And you could maybe have your character carry a small handwavium device around which relies on some possible future technological advance to hold the mouth at that end open.

### Sources:

- [Gao, P., Jafferis, D. L., & Wall, A. C. (2017). Traversable wormholes via a double trace deformation. Journal of High Energy Physics, 2017(12), 151.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05687)
- [Horowitz, G. T., Marolf, D., Santos, J. E., & Wang, D. (2019). Creating a traversable wormhole. Classical and Quantum Gravity, 36(20), 205011.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02187)